# Problems with compass

Tags: magento, ubuntu, compass

I recently install compass on ubuntu 15.04 and I'm having problems with it.  I'm using compass to style magento and after I make any changes I get this error:

/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/sass/selector/abstract_sequence.rb:96:in `block in _specificity': undefined method`specificity' for [:not(.block-layered-nav)]:Array

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.